# Method without parameters returning List in Web services

Tags: java, web-services

I have a Bean class that implements an interface. The Bean has several methods with some of them returning `List<...>`. The Web Service call is working for all the methods which does not return `List`. However I get a soap fault string when i try to invoke the method which returns `List` .

Here is my interface

```
@WebService
public interface Cart {

     @WebMethod(operationName="getOptionsData")   
     public List<OptionsData> getOptionsData(int id,int searchYear);
 }
```

Bean Class

```
@WebService 
public Class CartBean implements Cart {

@WebMethod(operationName="getOptionsData")
public List<OptionsData> getOptionsData(int id,int searchYear) {

  return List<...>;
}

}
```

When i try to invoke this using my web service , i get the following response message.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

 <soapenv:Body>
   <soapenv:Fault>  
      <faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>A Java method was not found for the operation. If the 
                  WSDL operation name is different from the Java method name, 
                  make sure that the @WebMethod annotation name is present
      </faultstring> 
      <detail />
    </soapenv:Fault>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have added both the annotations to my implementation class. However i dont understand why is it that only the method which returns `List<...>` and which takes parameters is not getting recognised.Methods which return `List<..>` with empty parameters is getting recognised and I am getting the response as expected.Is it that SOAP cannot handle `Lists` or is there anything wrong with the way i have implemented it? Somebody help me with this..

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: can u post small part of ur reponse from webservice?

Comment: @Android28 : I have updated the question with the response message

Comment: I encountered some weird error.I have updated the question. Please have a look and help me with this. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: if i m understanding right u r getting problem in response from web-service?m i right?

Comment: Yes.. I have posted the response message above

Comment: This problem occurs only when a method which takes one or more parameters and is returning a List<...>

Comment: is it posible for you to mail me ur code may be i can help you

Comment: I have mailed you the code.. Please have a look at it

Comment: hey , i thought u have android project..i could have helped u in android and its service

Comment: But its related to web services right.

Comment: ya but i handle the response of webservice in android

Answer (score 0):

SOAP definitely can handle `List<>`. I have working SOAP WebService implementations that returns `List<>`.

Problem is maybe in specification of your methods params.
Try to annotate your parameters like this:

```
...
import javax.jws.WebParam;
...
@WebMethod(operationName="getOptionsData")   
     public List<OptionsData> getOptionsData(@WebParam(name = "id")int id,
                                             @WebParam(name = "searchYear")int searchYear);
```

**UPDATE**

It' probably not supported by obsolete JAX-RPC. You should probably try to update to JAX-WS. You can follow tutorial below.

http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webservices_jaxws/

**UPDATE**
Tutorial for eclipse **Indigo**.
http://www.softwareagility.gr/index.php?q=node/29

Comment: in the interface or bean class??

Comment: I have been trying a simple web services example now.. When I tried to expose a method which returns List<..> it gave me this warning  'The service class "com.example.WebServices" does not comply to one or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or function correctly.
  The method "getString" on the service class "com.example.WebServices" uses a data type, "java.util.List", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.'

Comment: You are using JAX-RPC? thats pretty obsolete now. Is it possible for you to update to JAX-WS? http://finallyigotit.blogspot.cz/2009/05/jax-rpc-vs-jax-ws.html

Comment: When i try to create web service from ecipse i get the only option to do it through JAX-RPC.. How to update it to JAX-WS?

Comment: ok thanks. i will try with updating it to JAX-WS. So is it so that List is not getting recognised because of JAX-RPC?

Comment: Most probably. I have implemented many WS which returns `List<>`  using JAX-WS without any problems. With some hassle I even managed to return `Map<>`. JAX-RPC is obsolete if possible you should avoid it.

Comment: i am using eclipse indigo and based on the tutorial you have given,there is nothing called as web service project.. I am stuck at the very first part

Comment: You can try to download MyEclipse or Second tutorial I've just added to my answer.

Comment: i am using websphere now and tried using ibm websphere JAX-WS. Stil i am getting the same fault string for only those methods which return List

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem myself. Looks like SOAP cannot handle generics. Simple thing i did was to remove the generics and use just List. And my problem got solved

Answer (score -1):

You can get a JSON from your List and send the array of bytes of the JSON's file.

And in the calling method you get that array of bytes, create a temp file (if it's necessary), get the List from the JSON's file.

I do this is my application between Android and Java, and it's working fast than send the Object, because I zip the file too.

[]s
William Bertan

Comment: I dono how JSON exactly works. I am starting with web services for the first time. However that dint answer my question as to why the method which returns List<..> is not getting recognised while others do?

Comment: Ok, this doesn't answer directly your question, but it's another solution for your case. I don't know why, but I was stuck in the same question for a few days (in the beginning), and I give up and get working with XML at first, and next upgraded to JSON. Like I said, I boost performance with that, even when it's just an array of String, with JSON and zipping the JSON, I get better performance, because the JSON file was around 50Mb and zipped it is like 3Mb. Maybe you can give a shoot and try that, or wait for another response for your question.

Comment: As you said this doesn't answer my question. But i have heard of JSON and its performances. I am very curious to know why this is happening ? can u just put up a sample JSON snippet to start with?